# How to apply Gaussian naive bayes to predict traffic number in the future?

Tags: python, bayesian

I have got some historical data on traffic and would like to predict the future. 
I take reference from http://www.nuriaoliver.com/bicing/IJCAI09_Bicing.pdf. It applied the Bayesian network to predict the change in numbers of bikes, where I got the Bayesian network and would like to predict the changes by using Bayesian.

I faced several questions. I tried to use naive bayes to predict the number, but it seems naive bayes only allowed to have the output as several discrete class. In my case, the changes seem cannot be grouped into discrete class (like predicting a human is "male" or "female", only 2 discrete output to be the classifier)

May I know how can I apply the baysian approach in my case and what kind of python packages could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would see this as a time series forecasting problem and not a classification problem. As you noted, you are not trying to label your data into a set of discrete classes. Given a series of observations `x_1, x_2, .... x_n`, you are trying to predict `x_(n+1)` or trying forecast the next observation of the same variable in the series. Perhaps you could refer to [this](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching104/Ch14_slides.pdf) slide for a brief introduction to time series forecasting.

A quick start guide for time series forecasting with Python can be found here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-methods-in-python-cheat-sheet/